# How to retrieve multiple choice items using Client Object Model?

Tags: client-object-model, multiple-values, multi-select

There is a custom field in my list called "Solutions". The user can select multiple values for this field (they are in a set of checkboxes on the interface).

I get all the other values in the list with the code  `item.FieldValues["Solutions"].ToString();` but I'm unable to retrieve the multiple values this way.

Intellisense shows `FieldValues` as a dictionary entry, with the field name as key and the array as the value, but I can't parse it that way.

I've worked with the `SPFieldUserValueCollection`, so I know there must be a structure that will parse this out for me, but I can't find it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or give me a working example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no specific class for storing choice field value like in case of, for example, [user field value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduservalue.aspx) in CSOM API.

Since multiple choice field value is stored in string array, the following example demonstrates how to retrieve it:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);
ctx.Load(listItem);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var solutions = (string[])listItem["Solutions"];
//or
var solutionsList = new List<string>((string[])listItem["Solutions"]);

foreach (var solutionValue in solutions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(solutionValue);    
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't been casting it correctly.